# No mapping data was returned from the server in Visual Studio Page Inspector

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, page-inspector

To debug my web app, I need to run it on a specific domain. To do this I've created domain mappings in my hosts file, all mapping to 127.0.0.1. My site runs in my local IIS 8.

But when I try to run Page Inspector on the app, I get an error stating "No mapping data was returned from the server".

I've set up all the debugging URLs in project properties, and the site runs fine when I just hit F5.

How do I get Page Inspector to work on non-localhost URLs (or rather, how do I get my IIS to serve the mapping data that Page Inspector needs)?